# Jack server is not running or cannot be start error in raspberry pi python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

this is the error i'm getting when i run jarvis in raspberry pi
this is my jarvis code :-

```
import datetime
import pyttsx3
import random
import smtplib
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha

print("Initializing jarvis")

client = wolframalpha.Client('Your_App_ID')

engine = pyttsx3.init('espeak')
engine.rate = 300


def speak(audio):
    print('Jarvis: ' + audio)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def greetMe():
    currentH = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if currentH >= 0 and currentH < 12:
        speak('Good Morning!')

    if currentH >= 12 and currentH < 18:
        speak('Good Afternoon!')

    if currentH >= 18 and currentH !=0:
        speak('Good Evening!')

greetMe()

speak('Hello Raghavendra')


def myCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold =  1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print('User: ' + query + '\n')

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak('Say that again please')
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold =  1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    return query


if _name_ == '_main_':

    while True:

        query = myCommand()
        query = query.lower()

        if 'open youtube' in query:
            speak('okay')
            webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com')

        elif 'open google' in query:
            speak('okay')
            webbrowser.open('www.google.co.in')

        elif 'open gmail' in query:
            speak('okay')
            webbrowser.open('www.gmail.com')

        elif 'open whatsapp' in query:
            speak('okay')
            webbrowser.open('www.whatsapp.com')
        
        elif 'open bad boy song in youtube' in query:
            speak('okay')
            webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj3FIwVKjDo')

        elif "what\'s up" in query or 'how are you' in query:
            stMsgs = ['Just doing my thing!', 'I am fine!', 'Nice!', 'I am nice and full of energy']
            speak(random.choice(stMsgs))

        elif 'send email' in query:
            speak('Who is the recipient? ')
            recipient = myCommand()

            if 'Sunil Kumar' in recipient:
                try:
                    speak('What should I say? ')
                    content = myCommand()

                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.ehlo()
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login("gmail.com", '1234')
                    server.sendmail('gmail.com', "2gmail.com", content)
                    server.close()
                    speak('Email sent!')

                except:
                    speak('Sorry Raghavendra! I am unable to send your message at this moment!')

        elif 'jarvis'  in query:
            speak('okay')
            speak('Hello Raghavendra')
            sys.start()

        elif 'hello' in query:
            speak('Hello Raghavendra')

        elif 'bye' in query:
            speak('Bye Raghavendra, have a good day.')
            sys.exit()





        else:
            query = query
            speak('Searching...')
            try:
                try:
                    res = client.query(query)
                    results = next(res.results).text
                    speak('WOLFRAM-ALPHA says - ')
                    speak('Got it.')
                    speak(results)

                except:
                    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
                    speak('Got it.')
                    speak('WIKIPEDIA says - ')
                    speak(results)

            except:
                webbrowser.open('www.google.com')

        speak('Next Command! Raghavendra!')
```

How can i get rigid from this error?
i installed all module and i installed pyaudio but it is showing same error i connect my mic and  speaker to raspberry pi and i tested my mic and speakers it working fine but it is showing error in python.In computer i used sapi5 and it is working very well but in raspberry pi i'm getting error.

Comment: Please help me. I'm not getting any respond

Comment: please help me. anybody don't no the answer of this